# Unable to load a Visual Studio project from zip file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file, zip

I have Visual Studio 2015 web site project, and when I zip it or rar it and do extracting the project cannot be loaded (it is unavailable). This is the error that I get:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\new outlook 2\WebSites\OutlookDemo1\
>   Error opening web C:\Users\user\Desktop\new outlook 2\WebSites\OutlookDemo1.
>   Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\new outlook 2\WebSites\OutlookDemo1'.
>   The Web site 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\new outlook 2\WebSites\OutlookDemo1' does not exist.

Already tried a few things like deleting the suo file, but it did not help.

What can I do to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you use absolute path somewhere in you solution?

Comment: Its telling you that a file doesn't exist. Do you have relative or absolute file paths in your solution?

Comment: are you deploying whole project with source? suo file shouldn't even be there

Comment: What is absolute path?, Yes i am trying to open a whole project after i zipped it.